# pop up a new page within the same page in asp.net c# with jquery light box effect

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

How to open a new page with in the same page .

suppose we are in default.aspx page and click on a link new registration then the new registration.aspx page open in popup window with in the middle of the default.aspx page with  jquery light box effect.

Comment: Goto google and search for modal popup extender.

Comment: I want to use jquery light box effect

Comment: This new fangled thing called google... try it sometime... https://plugins.jquery.com/magnific-popup/ EDIT: let me save you another comment... http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ scroll down to popup form.